# ScrollView not MouseWheel Scrolling when not over Control

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

*I am using Silverlight 4.0*

What is happening is that the ScrollViewer will only scroll when one hovers over controls like textbox, treeviews, etc.

If the mouse is over non control objects (like grids) then the mousewheel scrolling doesn't work.

Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give the ScrollViewer a background.  If the background is transparent it will not catch any mouse events.

This is true with all controls.  If you are trying to catch mouse events the control must have a background or the controls below it will receive the mouse events.

Comment: For me, adding a Background="Transparent" property in the XAML fixed it.